# I want to remove the links from the term list returned by get_the_term_list

Tags: php, taxonomy, links, code

I want to keep this category title on my pages, but I don't want it to be a link.

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_cats', ' ', ' , ', ' '); ?>
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: How are you displaying the link on the page? Also move the code into a proper box for readability.

Comment: Same question here... https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23606/how-do-i-list-custom-taxonomy-terms-without-the-links/229572

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) and [`wp_sprintf_l()`](http://andy.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/wp_sprintf/):

```
function wpse_52878_term_list( $args = array() )
{
    $default = array (
        'id'               => get_the_ID(),
        'taxonomy'         => 'post_tag',
        'before'           => '',
        'after'            => '',
    );

    $options = array_merge( $default, $args );
    $terms   = get_the_terms( $options['id'], $options['taxonomy'] );
    $list    = array();

    foreach ( $terms as $term )
    {
        $list[] = $term->name;
    }
    return $options['before'] . wp_sprintf_l( '%l', $list ) . $options['after'];
}

echo wpse_52878_term_list( array ( 'id' => get_the_ID(), 'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_cats' ) );
```

---

Another option:

```
echo wp_strip_all_tags( 
    get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_cats', ' ', ' , ', ' ') 
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You just saved me a whole lot of time and stress!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this?

```
<?php
$portfolio_cats = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_cats', array('fields' => 'names'));
if(!empty($portfolio_cats)){
    if(!is_wp_error( $portfolio_cats )){
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($portfolio_cats as $term){
            echo '<li>'.$term->name'</li>'; 
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Try a print_r with the returned array to see the contents.

Comment: @joshua The Code is being used to display the category as the page header. However I don't want it to link back to a page containing all of the category items.

currently it displays like this:   

`<h1><a href="../portfolio-category/branding/"rel="tag"> Branding</a></h1>`

Comment: @joshua
Sorry I'm not sure how to put the code in a box.

`<?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_cats', ' ', ' , ', ' ') ?>`

Comment: You should use `get_the_terms` instead of `wp_get_object_terms`. `wp_get_object_terms` bypasses WordPress' caching, and essentially means you query the database with every call.