# How to retrieve taxonomy terms of the current custom post?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, breadcrumb

I have a custom taxonomy *worktype* and I have 3 types in this latter custom taxonomy:
- creation
- collaboration
- lab

I have also a custom post type "works".
*worktype* is used only for the custom posts type *works*

I have single-works.php as a template and everything is ok

BUT, I need to retrieve the worktype of the current single post.
How can I do that ?

(the final idea: build a breadcrumb like that  >  ; in order to navigate a bit better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy )`:

```
$worktypes = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'worktyp' );

var_export( $worktypes );
```

You can also use …

```
get_the_term_list( $id, $taxonomy, $before = '', $sep = '', $after = '' );
```

… to get a formatted output. [Example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52889/73).